# Ruby on rails server on mobile

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, mobile

I'm trying to install rails server on my android mobile to explore some capabilities further. But want to know first how easy is to install rails server running on mobile and steps to follow.

Thanks

Comment: Solution has been explained in this post [Installation](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/74876)